# google-cloud-recommendation How to get next page for Prediction?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-recommendation

I want to use [predict](https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.placements/predict) method in order to get recommendation devided by page.
This method has `pageToken` parameter used for paging. The parameter should be received in the previous prediction response.
But this method in v2 API doesn't return `pageToken` or `nextPageToken` that is in v1beta1 API.
Why it disappeared? How can I get next page for prediction?

Request url is
`https://retail.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{PROJECT_NUMBER}/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/placements/recently_viewed_default:predict`

Request body is

```
{
  "filter": "tag=(\"成人作品\") filterOutOfStockItems",
  "userEvent": {
    "eventType": "home-page-view",
    "visitorId": "1254704470.1607003607",
    "productDetails": [
      {
        "product": {
          "id": "220604"
        },
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The response is here. There is no `nextPageToken`

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "170706"
    },
    {
      "id": "64081"
    },
          :
       (snip)
          :
    {
      "id": "132940"
    },
    {
      "id": "17557"
    }
  ],
  "attributionToken": "ChQxNzkzOTg1NDI3MTk1OTMyNzU0MhACGiNvZnRlbl9wdXJjX2ZyZXF1ZW50bHlfMTYxNDMwNjk3OTQyNSIYb2Z0ZW5fcHVyY2hhc2VkX3RvZ2V0aGVyKAA"
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the request and response.

Comment: Can you share the request composition as was previously asked?

Comment: I add request and response.  I decided not to use pagenation in API, but I'm still curious about it . Please answer if you have any time. Thank you.

Comment: It seems this affects either v2 or v2beta APIs. If you want this feature back, file a feature request via [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)?  Does it sound reasonable for you?